How can I mint more tokens for my meme coin?
I launched a meme coin today, And I burned entire LP & also sold all my tokens from my dev wallet (Its Empty now). This meme coin did not go well & is already dead, But their is still money inside and it is entirely my money because there's no additional holder.
I had kept mint authority enabled. Do I still have the authority to mint more tokens? If yes how can I mint more coins to dump & get my money out?
Please help, thanks!

You can you mint more if you did not disable Mint Authority
Use Rugcheck.xyz to check
And then you can use tools or the CLI
spl-token mint [address] [amount]

More instructions can you be here https://solana.com/docs/core/tokens#mint-tokens

if you still have mint authority you can mint new tokens.
Hypersol provides ability to mint and burn tokens.
https://app.hypersol.xyz/solana-token-manager/update-token
After loading your token, on mint section it will show if you have mint authority or not, if you have it will give you an option to mint token.

If you have retained minting authority and there are still funds within the contract, technically you have ability to mint more tokens.
